# Unable to upload files to cpanel server

Tags: php, upload, cpanel

How do I get files to upload online? This works well locally, but I cannot get the file to upload online to my cpanel server.  I cannot see the path in my database, and the file is not uploaded into the `researches` file.

Here is my code:

```
if($name=="") echo "Enter the Research Title.<br/>";
else{
        $uploadfile = basename($_FILES['imageupload']['name']);
        $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["imageupload"]["tmp_name"];

        $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "researches/".$uploadfile);

        $path = $uploadfile.".pdf";

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO researches (name, link, date) VALUES ('$name', '$path', '$date')");

        echo "Research Uploaded successfully.<br/>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2, url=researches.php' >";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have write permission on that folder?

Comment: @stijn it worked thanks all i had to do was check the permissions silly me...

Comment: You probably meant @Pitchinnate ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope "researches" is a DB in which you want to INSERT files every time you needed. If that is not allowing to upload (INSERT) files to the DB, Make sure that the DB user is having necessary privileges to perform the action.

Anyway I don't see anything regarding DB user. You simply give all privileges to the corresponding DB user for the DB researches.